# Problema insertando datos con MySQLi

Tags: php, sql, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysqli

Tengo esta base de datos creada en phpMyAdmin:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema que tengo es que al momento de insertar los datos del formulario donde creo un usuario logra conectarse a la base de datos, los datos los envía pero no los guarda, concluyendo con la redirección a otra página.

Éste es mi código:

```
<?php
$servername ="mysql.hostinger.es";
$username ="user";
$password = "pass";
$dbname = "db";
$con=mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbname );
//check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

//add details in database
if (isset($_POST['usuario']) and isset($_POST['pass'])) {
    $user = $_POST['usuario'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO cuentas (usuarios, clave)
VALUES ($user, $pass)");
}
header("Location: resultado.html");

?>
```

¿Qué es lo que falla? ¿Qué debería cambiar? Espero que me puedan ayudar con este problema.

Comment: ¿Qué error te notifica a la hora de insertar los datos?
Si quitas la redirección te mostrará el error o bien, es que la sentencia if no se compute como deseas. ¿Has comprobado que realmente la sentencia *if* sea procesada correctamente? `if (isset($_POST['usuario']) and isset($_POST['pass']))` Prueba de la siguiente manera: `if ((isset($_POST['usuario'])) && (isset($_POST['pass'])))`

Comment: Independientemente del problema, el código de arriba puede sufrir ataques de inyección SQL. Usar `PDO` y `mysqli_*` es un buen comienzo, pero por sí solos no son suficientes para evitar esos ataques; deberías además usar consultas parametrizadas (o preparadas).

Answer (score 8):

El error está en cómo estás insertando los datos en la base de datos: faltan algunas comillas.

En tu tabla `cuentas`, los campos `usuarios` y `clave` son alfanuméricos (`varchar(30)` ambos), y entonces debería ir entre comillas simples en el `INSERT`, pero van sin comillas de ningún tipo.

Por ejemplo, el código actual genera:

```
INSERT INTO cuentas (usuarios, clave) VALUES (Alvaro Montoro, Contraseña)
```

Que fallará porque tanto `Alvaro Montoro` como `Contraseña` no son nombres de columnas ni de variables conocidas.

El código debería ser algo así:

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO cuentas (usuarios, clave) VALUES ('$user', '$pass')");
```

Que entonces generaría lo siguiente:

```
INSERT INTO cuentas (usuarios, clave) VALUES ('Alvaro Montoro', 'Contraseña')
```

Y funcionaría sin problemas.

---

Aparte de eso (y como mencioné en los comentarios) deberías usar consultas parametrizadas porque el código actual (y la solución aquí puesta basada en ese código) pueden sufrir ataques de inyección de SQL.

El cambio es muy simple y ganarías mucho en seguridad (para evitar casos como el de [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/), en inglés). Sería algo así:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO cuentas (usuarios, clave) VALUES (?, ?)";
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) {
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $user, $pass);
    $stmt->execute();
    ...
}
```

Nota: Fíjate como ahora ya no hacen falta las comillas, porque como especificas que los parámetros van a ser `string` (las "ss"), entonces mysqli las añade sin necesidad de que hagas nada más.